# How to Add Dynamic Meta tags Using php

Tags: php, jquery, seo, meta-tags

I Fetch Data From Laravel API and I want to show dynamic meta title and description but when i set dynamic data in inspect element it show's dynamic values but not updated in page source and also when share on social media like whatsapp, facebook etc it not showing dynamic title and description.

Here is My Code..

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#084594" />
<meta property="og:title" id='metaTitle' content="Static Title">
<meta property="og:description" id='metaDescription' content="Static Description">
```

Now I am Change it Using Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  const API = "<?= API ?>";
  $('#metaTitle').attr('content','Dynamic Title')
  $('#metaDescription').attr('content','Dynamic Description')
  function getCategory() {
   
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: `${API}/all_category`,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("responseCat", response.category);
        $.each(response.category, function(key, item) {
          let cat = item.name.split(' ')[0];
          $("#filter").append(
            `<li data-filter=".${cat}"><a href="#">${item.name}</a></li>`
          );
        });
        isotopFilter();
      },
    });
  }

  function getPortfolio() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: `${API}/all_portfolios`,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("responseCat", response.portfolio);
        $.each(response.portfolio, function(key, item) {
          let cat = item.category.split(' ')[0];
          let url_title = item.title.toLowerCase().replace(/[ ().]/g, '-');
          url_title = url_title.replace('--', '-');
          $(".masonry_wrapper").append(
            `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 flex-active item ${cat}"><div class="tutorial_card"> <div class="service-content"> <a href="portfolio/${url_title}" > <h3>${item.title}</h3></a > </div><div class="read"> <a href="portfolio/${url_title}" class="btn btn-default" >View Portfolio</a > </div></div></div`
          );
        });
        isotopFilter();
      },
    });
  }

  
  getCategory();
  getPortfolio();
});
```

But It is showing Static Title And Description in ctrl + u Page Source code But In Inspect Elements It change With Dynamic Title And Description.
And Also When Share Page It Shows Static Title And Description

Comment: "View source code" shows ... the source code, delivered by your server. Same for sharing a page, no JS is applied. Change your meta tags serverside, not clientside

Comment: @brombeer can you please tell me how to do that..

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Getting the data from your API into PHP? (Use cURL/Guzzle) Assigning values to a variable and using it in your HTML? Are you using a templating engine?

Comment: No iam using .php file and Get Data From API And Assign To Variable But it can not show when i share on whatsapp and other social media

Comment: So if you already got the data and assigned it to a variable you only need to output it where you want it in your HTML: `<meta property="og:title" id='metaTitle' content="<?php echo $dynamicTitleVariable ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

As @brombeer already stated in the comments, most social media and robots don't care about the **client side** changes (Javascript is executed on the client's computer).

You'll need to set the meta properties on the **server side**, using PHP.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that..

Comment: Since you are using Laravel, you'll need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676729/add-meta-tags-to-laravel-page